# Is my Double-Checked Locking Pattern implementation right?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, atomic, double-checked-locking

An example in Meyers's book *Effective Modern C++*, Item 16.

> in a class caching an expensive-to-compute int, you might try to use a
>   pair of std::atomic avriables instead of a mutex:

```
class Widget {
public:
    int magicValue() const {
        if (cachedValid) {
            return cachedValue;
        } else {
            auto val1 = expensiveComputation1();
            auto val2 = expensiveComputation2();

            cachedValue = va1 + val2;
            cacheValid = true;
            return cachedValue;
        }
    }
private:
    mutable std::atomic<bool> cacheValid { false };
    mutable std::atomic<int> cachedValue;
};
```

> This will work, but sometimes it will work a lot harder than it
>   should.Consider: A thread calls Widget::magicValue, sees cacheValid as
>   false, performs the two expensive computations, and assigns their sum
>   to cachedValud. At that point, a second thread calss
>   Widget::magicValue, also sees cacheValid as false, and thus carries
>   out the same expensive computations that the first thread has just
>   finished.

Then he gives a solution with mutex:

```
class Widget {
public:
    int magicValue() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
        if (cacheValid) {
            return cachedValue;
        } else {
            auto val1 = expensiveComputation1();
            auto val2 = expensiveComputation2();

            cachedValue = va1 + val2;
            cacheValid = true;
            return cachedValue;
        }
    }
private:
    mutable std::mutex m;
    mutable bool cacheValid { false };
    mutable int cachedValue;
};
```

But I think the solution is not so effecient, I consider to combine mutex and atomic to make up a **Double-Checked Locking Pattern** as below.

```
class Widget {
public:
    int magicValue() const {
        if (!cacheValid)  {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
            if (!cacheValid) {
                auto val1 = expensiveComputation1();
                auto val2 = expensiveComputation2();

                cachedValue = va1 + val2;
                cacheValid = true;
            }
        }
        return cachedValue;
    }
private:
    mutable std::mutex m;
    mutable std::atomic<bool> cacheValid { false };
    mutable std::atomic<int> cachedValue;
};
```

Because I am a newbie in multithread programming, so I want to know：

- Is my code right?
- Does it performance better ?

**EDIT:**

---

Fixed the code.**if (!cachedValue) -> if (!cacheValid)**

Comment: In principle, yes, you are right. But if we assume the computations take a lot longer than setting the atomics, the likelihood of your scenario is very low, and using the atomics avoid expensive mutexes.

Comment: I think your approach is correct and better than the previous two. It just explained the *Double-Checked Locking Pattern*.

Comment: I don't think it is correct, if a second thread evaluates the cacheValid after the first has evaluated but before the guard is instantiated. I think the impact may be equal to the first example.

Comment: It's hard to tell if your code is legal/safe without seeing how `cachedValue` gets set to `false`.

Comment: @Lingxi I have just fixed the code,

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `mutable std::atomic<bool> cacheValid { false };`. `magicValue` can only be called on a constructed object. And for this, `cacheValid` must have already been initialized to `false` before that.

Comment: @HappyCactus I have fixed the type error , sorrry for mislead

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin: **cachedValid** variable actually has name **cacheValid**. Please, fix this in all code you provide (even in the book's snippets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my code right?

Yes. You application of Double-Checked Locking Pattern is correct. But see below for some improvements.

> Does it performance better ?

When compared with fully locked variant(2nd in your post), it mostly has better performance, until `magicValue()` is called only once(but even in that case performance losses are negligibly small).

When compared with lockless variant(1st in your post), your code show better perfomance, until value computing is faster than *waiting on mutex*.

E.g., *sum of 10 values* is (usually) **faster** than *waiting on mutex*. In that case 1st variant is preferrable. From the other side, *10 reads from file* is **slower** than *waiting on mutex*, so your variant is better then 1st.

---

Actually, there are simple improvemnts to your code, which make it faster (at least, on some machines) and improve code's understanding:

1. `cachedValue` variable doesn't require atomic semantic at all. It is protected by `cacheValid` flag, which atomicity do all the work. Moreover, single atomic flag can protect several non-atomic values.
2. Also, as noted in that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30049946/3440745, when access to `cacheValid` flag you don't need sequential consistency order(which is applied by default when you simply read or write atomic variable), release-acquire order is sufficient.

---

```
class Widget {
public:
    int magicValue() const {
        //'Acquire' semantic when read flag.
        if (!cacheValid.load(std::memory_order_acquire))  { 
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
            // Reading flag under mutex locked doesn't require any memory order.
            if (!cacheValid.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                auto val1 = expensiveComputation1();
                auto val2 = expensiveComputation2();

                cachedValue = va1 + val2;
                // 'Release' semantic when write flag
                cacheValid.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
            }
        }
        return cachedValue;
    }
private:
    mutable std::mutex m;
    mutable std::atomic<bool> cacheValid { false };
    mutable int cachedValue; // Atomic isn't needed here.
};
```

Comment: `cachedValue` need not be atomic in this solution, because writing to it is protected by the mutex. In the code in Meyers' book (and in the suggested solution by Maxim Egorushkin below), there is no mutex preventing multiple threads from simultaneously assigning to `cachedValue` (all such threads will have seen a `cacheValid` value of `false` at the top of the function). In that case, it's important that `cachedValue` be atomic, because otherwise simultaneous writes to it yield undefined behavior.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: `cachedValue` is already not atomic in this solution. If you mean `cacheValid`, it should be atomic, because it is checked (first time) out of mutex protection This is main feature of DCLP, that flag should be either *volatile*(in languages where this term is thread-related, e.g. java) or *atomic*.

Comment: My comment was just that: a comment. I agree that the given implementation is fine (and said so), but in your point 1 above the code, you write that "`cachedValue` variable doesn't require atomic semantic at all [because] it is protected by `cacheValid` flag." That's not true. `cachedValue` need not be atomic, because it's protected by the mutex. As I noted in my comment on Maxim Egorushkin's answer below, if there is no mutex, both `cacheValid` and `cachedValue` must be atomic.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: Expression `return cachedValue;` is not protected by the mutex, so one cannot say that `cachedValue` variable is protected by the mutex. Mutex protects only *some* accesses, and prevent concurrent writting.

Comment: The return statement is a read. Simultaneous reads are not a problem, hence don't need to be protected.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: No, accesses to variable are said to be protected by mutex only when *all* accesses to that variable are performed with mutex locked. Without appropritate accesses to `cacheValid` variable, given example would be raced on `cachedValue` variable (and broken).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by HappyCactus, the second check `if (!cachedValue)` should actually be `if (!cachedValid)`. Except this typo, I think your demonstration of the Double-Checked Locking Pattern is correct. However, I think it is unnecessary to use `std::atomic` on `cachedValue`. The only place where `cachedValue` is written to is `cachedValue = va1 + val2;`. Before it is completed, no thread will ever reach the statement `return cachedValue;` which is the only place `cachedValue` is read. Therefore, it is impossible for a write and a read to be concurrent. And there is no problem with concurrent reads.

Comment: Making it atomic is necessary: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html. Since the flag is atomic, its write may be synchronized across processors, while the non-atomic value is not. So you could see cacheValid = true but cacheValue = /* uninitialized on this processor */

Comment: @BillyONeal No. The memory order semantics used on `cacheValid` is `memory_order_seq_cst`. It establishes the required synchronization relationships. When `cacheValid` is read `true`, the modification to `cacheValue` must also be seen on the same processor. This is actually why atomics can be used to order non-atomics.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your solution slightly more efficient by reducing the memory ordering requirements. The default sequential consistency memory order for atomic operations is not necessary here.

The performance difference may be negligible on x86, but noticeable on ARM, because sequential consistency memory order is expensive on ARM. See [“Strong” and “weak” hardware memory models by Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2012/08/02/strong-and-weak-hardware-memory-models/) for more details.

Suggested changes:

```
class Widget {
public:
    int magicValue() const {
        if (cachedValid.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) { // Acquire semantics.
            return cachedValue;
        } else {
            auto val1 = expensiveComputation1();
            auto val2 = expensiveComputation2();

            cachedValue = va1 + val2; // Non-atomic write.

            // Release semantics.
            // Prevents compiler and CPU store reordering.
            // Makes this and preceding stores by this thread visible to other threads.
            cachedValid.store(true, std::memory_order_release); 
            return cachedValue;
        }
    }
private:
    mutable std::atomic<bool> cacheValid { false };
    mutable int cachedValue; // Non-atomic.
};
```

Comment: Have you considered the situation *: A thread calls Widget::magicValue, sees cacheValid as false, performs the two expensive computations, and assigns their sum to cachedValud. At that point, a second thread calss Widget::magicValue, also sees cacheValid as false, and thus carries out the same expensive computations that the first thread has just finished.*

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin If calculating `cachedValue` must only be done once, you probably may like to use a mutex.

Comment: Downvoted, because if two threads read `cacheValid` as `false`, both will compute `cachedValue`, and if both make an assignment to `cachedValue` at the same time, you have two threads writing to a non-atomic at once, and that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: Concurrent writting *same* value into variable is OK for all known C++ implementation. Probably, C++ standard also notes that, but I don't remember where it does so.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: As far as I know, it's undefined behavior, and there's an example of how it can go wrong in [this paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotpar11/tech/final_files/Boehm.pdf).

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: Section 2.4. of the paper you reffer to says: " It seems unlikely on any conventional architecture that a store would
be implemented such that rewriting the same bits would result in a final value different from either of the written values". All futher examples are not applicable to the given code as it doesn't access `cachedValue` before writting. The only exception is "note 6", which tells about SPARC's  "block initializing store" instruction.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: In terms of undefined behavior, the only document that matters is the C++ standard. To the best of my knowledge, simultaneous writes to a single memory location always yield undefined behavior, even if both writes are of the same value. The paper I cited simply explains circumstances--even theoretical ones--that could explain how UB could arise. Are you aware of something in the Standard that says that unsynchronized writes to a single memory location yield well-defined behavior if both writes are of the same value?

Answer (score -1):

It is not correct:

```
int magicValue() const {
    if (!cachedValid)  {

        // this part is unprotected, what if a second thread evaluates
        // the previous test when this first is here? it behaves 
        // exactly like in the first example.

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
        if (!cachedValue) {
            auto val1 = expensiveComputation1();
            auto val2 = expensiveComputation2();

            cachedValue = va1 + val2;
            cachedValid = true;
        }
    }
    return cachedValue;
```

Comment: I don't think it's a problem for multiple threads to be in `this part`.

Comment: It is, unless the second test should be read as "CachedValid" and not "CachedValue". I didn't guess it might be a typo, but it is obvious it is.

Comment: You have a pair of sharp eyes :-) Didn't notice the typo.